# Why are old values in an array still present?

Tags: c, arrays, string

Please explain this output. The problem is same with scanf. How can the array be reinitialized everytime?
Input:

```
HelloWorld
Tech
```

Output:

```
eo  
Tech
TW
```

Code:

```
#include<stdio.h>  
#include<string.h>  
int main()  
{  char c[1024]; int i,d=1;  
 gets(c);  
 printf("%c%c\n",c[d],c[d+5]);  
 gets(c);    
 puts(c);  
 printf("%c%c\n",c[0],c[4+d]);  
 return 0;  
 }
```

Comment: Welcome to [SO], this feels like homework, you don't seem to have a problem that needs to be solved. Please read [ask] and [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In C, strings are stored as [null-terminated](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null-terminated_string) arrays of characters. This means that there are many ways to represent the same string: everything in the array of characters after the first null byte is ignored, as far as the value of the string is concerned.

When the first `gets` call reads `HelloWorld`, it stores the character `'H'` in `c[0]`, `'e'` in `c[1]`, …, `'d'` in `c[9]` and 0 (that's a null byte, not `'0'`) in `c[10]`. The contents of `c[11]` through `c[1023]` are unchanged.

When the second `gets` call reads `Tech`, it stores the character `'T'` in `c[0]`, `'e'` in `c[1]`, `'c'` in `c[2]`, `'h'` in `c[3]` and 0 in `c[4]`. The contents of `c[5]` through `c[1023]` are unchanged. In particular, `c[5]` still has the value `W` that was set by the first `gets` call.

If you're used to high-level languages, you might expect that `gets` allocates new storage, or that doing what looks like a string access guarantees that you're actually accessing the string, but neither of these is true.

As you might guess from the fact that you pass an array of characters to `gets`, it merely writes to that array of characters, it doesn't allocate new storage. When `gets` reads a 4-byte string, it writes that 4-byte string plus the terminating null byte, and it doesn't touch whatever comes after those 5 bytes. In fact, `gets` doesn't even know the size of the array (which is why `gets` is practically unusable in practice and has been removed from the current version of the C language: if you input a line that's too long for the array, it will overwrite whatever comes after the array in memory).

`c[5]` accesses the element of the array `c` at position 5. This happens to be outside the string, but that's not relevant to how an array access operates. It's an *array* access, not a *string* access. C doesn't really have strings natively: it fakes them with arrays of characters. String manipulation functions treat their arguments as strings (i.e. they only look up to the first null byte). But an array access is just an array access, and it's up to the programmer not to access the string, or the array, out of bounds.

Answer (score 0):

Please correct your indications. You may want to use 2, 3, 4 spaces, but 1 just looks wrong. I don't see any use of the `string.h` library.

---

The array is not cleared, but the 0..3 characters are replaced with the new ones and character on position 4 is `\0`. That's why you can read character from previously entered value at position 5 in this array.